# Generate list of new and modified files on an FTP server using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: powershell, email, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I've a PowerShell script that detects when a new file is uploaded on a FTP server.
I want to include list of such files (it's possible that they have multiple files) to a mail.
I already have the part of the script for add it to the mail and send it (I think I've done this in right way), but I only need the name of the file and not on the full path.
FYI : I'm using the winscpnet.dll library.

Have you a idea how to do it?

This is the script :

```
param (
    # Use Generate Session URL function to obtain a value for -sessionUrl parameter.
    $sessionUrl = "xxxxxxx",
    $remotePath = "xxxxxxx"
)

### SENDING MAIL FONCTION IF NEW FILE ###
Function SendMail-New
{
    $EXPEDITEUR = "xxxxxxx"
    $DESTINATAIRE = "xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx"
    $SUJET = "xxxxxxx"
    $SERVEUR_SMTP = "sxxxxxxx" 
    $CORPS_MAIL = "xxxxxxx"
    #$PJ = ($added -Join "`n") # If attached file
    #$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($PJ) # For attached file
    $Mail_Message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage # Creating mail object
    $Mail_Message.From = $EXPEDITEUR
    $Mail_Message.Subject = $SUJET
    $Mail_Message.Body = $CORPS_MAIL
    #$Mail_Message.Attachments.Add($PJ)
    $Mail_Adresses = $Mail_Message.To
    if ($DESTINATAIRE -is "System.Array") # If more than 1 adress
    {
        foreach ($Adr in $DESTINATAIRE) # Adding each mail adress
        {
            $Mail_Adress = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress $Adr
            $Mail_Adresses.Add($Mail_Adress)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $Mail_Adress = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress $DESTINATAIRE
        $Mail_Adresses.Add($Mail_Adress)
    }
    $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SERVEUR_SMTP, xxxxxxx) # SMTP server and port
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false # If SSL his activated or not - import the certificate before ?
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx"); #ICI Login et password du compte mail
    $SMTPClient.Send($Mail_Message) # Mail sending
}

### SENDING MAIL FONCTION IF DELETED FILE ###
Function SendMail-Deleted
{
    $EXPEDITEUR = "xxxxxxx"
    $DESTINATAIRE = "xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx"
    $SUJET = "xxxxxxx"
    $SERVEUR_SMTP = "xxxxxxx" 
    $CORPS_MAIL = "xxxxxxx"
    #$PJ = 'c:\script\Rapport.txt' # If attached file
    #$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($PJ) # For attached file
    $Mail_Message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage # Creating mail object
    $Mail_Message.From = $EXPEDITEUR
    $Mail_Message.Subject = $SUJET
    $Mail_Message.Body = $CORPS_MAIL
    #$Mail_Message.Attachments.Add($PJ)
    $Mail_Adresses = $Mail_Message.To
    if ($DESTINATAIRE -is "System.Array") # If more than 1 adress
    {
        foreach ($Adr in $DESTINATAIRE) # Adding each mail adress
        {
            $Mail_Adress = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress $Adr
            $Mail_Adresses.Add($Mail_Adress)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $Mail_Adress = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress $DESTINATAIRE
        $Mail_Adresses.Add($Mail_Adress)
    }
    $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SERVEUR_SMTP, xxxxxxx) # SMTP server and port
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false # If SSL his activated or not - import the certificate before ?
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx"); #ICI Login et password du compte mail
    $SMTPClient.Send($Mail_Message) # Mail sending
}

### SENDING MAIL FONCTION FOR A SCRIPT ERROR ###
Function SendMail-Error
{
    $EXPEDITEUR = "xxxxxxx"
    $DESTINATAIRE = "xxxxxxx"
    $SUJET = "xxxxxxx"
    $SERVEUR_SMTP = "xxxxxxx" 
    $CORPS_MAIL = "Le script c'est fermé suite à une erreur: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    #$PJ = 'c:\script\Rapport.txt' # If attached file
    #$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($PJ) # For attached file
    $Mail_Message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage # Creating mail object
    $Mail_Message.From = $EXPEDITEUR
    $Mail_Message.Subject = $SUJET
    $Mail_Message.Body = $CORPS_MAIL
    #$Mail_Message.Attachments.Add($PJ)
    $Mail_Adresses = $Mail_Message.To
    if ($DESTINATAIRE -is "System.Array") # If more than 1 adress
    {
        foreach ($Adr in $DESTINATAIRE) # Adding each mail adress
        {
            $Mail_Adress = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress $Adr
            $Mail_Adresses.Add($Mail_Adress)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $Mail_Adress = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress $DESTINATAIRE
        $Mail_Adresses.Add($Mail_Adress)
    }
    $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SERVEUR_SMTP, xxxxxxx) # SMTP server and port
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false # If SSL his activated or not - import the certificate before ?
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx"); #ICI Login et password du compte mail
    $SMTPClient.Send($Mail_Message) # Mail sending
}

try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"
 
    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
    $sessionOptions.ParseUrl($sessionUrl)
 
    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
 
    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)
 
        $prevFiles = $Null;
 
        while ($True)
        {
            # Collect file list
            $files =
                $session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
                    $remotePath, "*.*", [WinSCP.EnumerationOptions]::AllDirectories) |
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
 
            if ($prevFiles -eq $Null)
            {
                # In the first round, just print number of files found
                Write-Host "Found $($files.Count) files"
            }
            else
            {
                # Then look for differences against the previous list
                $changes = Compare-Object -DifferenceObject $files -ReferenceObject $prevfiles
 
                $added =
                    $changes |
                    Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" } |
                    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
                if ($added)
                {
                    Write-Host "Added files:"
                    Write-Host ($added -Join "`n")
                    Write-Warning "xxxxxxx"
                    SendMail-New # Send notification by mail for NEW FILE
                    echo "Mail envoyé"
                }
 
                $removed =
                    $changes |
                    Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" } |
                    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
                if ($removed)
                {
                    Write-Host "Removed files:"
                    Write-Host ($removed -Join "`n")
                    Write-Warning "Un rapport d'intervention a été supprimé"
                    SendMail-Deleted # Send notification by mail for DELETED FILE
                    echo "Mail envoyé"
                }
            }
 
            $prevFiles = $files
 
            Write-Host "Sleeping 10s..."
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }
}
catch
{
    SendMail-Error
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    echo "Mail d'erreur envoyé"
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you do not have any subfolders in your comparison. Otherwise your requirement would not make sense to me.

If that assumption is correct, just compare plain file names (`Name`) instead of full paths (`FullName`). And exclude subfolders (`[WinSCP.EnumerationOptions]::None`), to make it clear that the code does not support them anymore.

```
$files =
    $session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
        $remotePath, "*.*", [WinSCP.EnumerationOptions]::None) |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```